# Path to get a subset of nodes

Tags: algorithm

I had a pretty interesting interview question today.

I have one chip chip (say, yellow) and a series of offers from one chip to two chips (one yellow -> one green, one blue). What is the minimum number of trades I have to do to achieve a result set.

So let's say I start with a color `A`, and I need to get the colors `D, E, F, G`,

```
A
A -> B, C
B -> D, E
C -> F, G
```

I can trade A to B, C, and trade those two to get D, E, F, G.

What algorithm did I needed to solve this? Working backwards from the result set was something but it's quite tricky as the trades can loop (one A chip for two A chips). It seems like a Graph problem. MST looks eeriely similar, but it's undirected, and in my case, I can repeat trades (non-unique paths).

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic will suffice, no program/algorithm needed.

Since each trade changes the number of chips you have by the same amount (which is one), you can just divide the difference in chips between your set and the goal set by the change in set size:

```
chipsIn = 1
chipsOut = 2
changePerTrade = chipsOut - chipsIn
numTrades = (goalSet.size - startSet.size) / changePerTrade
```

A few caveats:

Note that this only works because of the limitation that all the trades have the same input and output size, and works under the assumption that every chip you have counts toward the goal set (for example having ABC is a failure if you are trying to get AB).

This will only tell you the minimum number of trades (which also happens to be the maximum number of trades), not whether or not it is even possible to achieve the goal set.

---

A more general purpose way to solve the problem would be to explore the tree of possibilities.

This is simply a search of a tree, where you are generating the nodes in the tree as it is explored. Your tree would look something like (for your example):

```
            A
            |
           B,C
         /     \
    D,E,C       B,F,G
      |           |
   D,E,F,G     D,E,F,G
```

where the tree continues and every node is a set (or list if duplicates are allowed) of chips. A few ideas to help explain the concept of the tree:

1. Moving down the tree represents working forwards.
2. Moving down one branch represents a single trade.
3. Since you are trying to find the fewest number of trades and all trades increase the size of your set by 1, you only need to explore `goalSet.size` levels of the tree.

You start at node A and loop through all your chips and perform each possible trade one at a time, going a level deeper every time you do so.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) is a wikipedia article explaining how to do a tree traversal, which you can tweak to create nodes as you explore them. Depth first search will be easiest since you only have to track one node at a time, but breadth first search would likely be faster, although more of an implementation pain.